# Expresso Store Promotional Codes

Tags: expresso-store, coupon-code

If we have someone using promotional codes in the checkout tag, is there any way to pull out and display what promo code has been used, once applied? I am thinking in the notes section of the promo code area, I could put something informative in there, and once a promo code is used, push this out to the checkout code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yip, `{promo_code}` should do it. It's just a regular order field in that regard.

Update: Looks like you actually want more details about the discount other than just the promo code. In that case, you could use the `{exp:query}` module with some simple SQL like this (inside the checkout tag):

```
select * from exp_store_discounts where id = '{discount_id}'
```